# Point of contact in a moving point-circle collision using FreePacal/Lazarus

Tags: lazarus, freepascal

I need to program a game in Lazarus/Freepascal. In this game, the player has the ability to "jump" from planet to planet, like [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VgUxm.jpg).

The jumping *itself* is implemented, but the landing doesn't work. At first I tried to calculate the right position for my player character using the law of cosine, but that didn't really work out. Then I tried to get the right position by rearranging the code I use for movement:

```
if getkeystate(vk_left) < 0 then
begin
  currotp1 := currotp1 - 2;
end;

if getkeystate(vk_right) < 0 then
begin
  currotp1 := currotp1 + 2;
end;

edit1.Text := IntToStr(currotp1);
GTR.left := trunc(-cos(currotp1 / 180 + pi) * (-r)) + curplaxp1;
GTR.top := trunc(-sin(currotp1 / 180 + pi) * (-r)) + curplayp1;

while currotp1 > 1130 do
begin

  currotp1 := currotp1 - 1130;

end;

while currotp1 < 0 do
begin

  currotp1 := currotp1 + 1130;

end;
```

Turned into:

```
addrotp1 := (-arccos(DegToRad((GTR.top - yorigins[notplanump1]) / (- 
rs[notplanump1]))) - pi) * 180;

currotp1 := round(addrotp1);
```

For clarification:

- Currotp1 is the current rotationvalue of player one. 1130 "units" is one full 
  rotation
- GTR.left and GTR.top are the coordinates of my player
- r is the radius of the "planet" the player is on
- curplxp1 and curplayp1 are the coordinates of the center of the planet the 
  player is on.
- addrotp1 is the additional rotation I want to apply on the player. It's 
  float.
- yorigins[notplanump1] and xorigins[notplanump1] are the coordinates of the 
  planet the player is *not* on.
- rs[notlpanump1] is the radius of the planet the player is *not* on.

Please suggest approaches/solutions to solve this problem.

Comment: Are you sure you don't mean currotp1/180 * pi instead of + pi ?

Comment: Yes, or I  _should_ have meant at in the first place. Now one rotation equals 360 degrees and not 1130 "units". Thank you!

Comment: Which is why conversion routines are safer https://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/rtl/math/degtorad.html